# c# ClickOnce , notify app of the updates

Tags: c#, clickonce

HI,
Currently application is requesting for the update using CheckForUpdateAsync(),

Now we want the application to stay quite and let the **update** notify the application if any update is available. Then we retrieve the updates in a background thread only if notified. 
Application is not supposed to check for updates.

If any solution or its possible, then plz suggest

thanx..

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the **update** is not an application in its own right--it is the passive existence of the new ClickOnce deployment files associated with a new version.  You might want to use a FileSystemWatcher object from the .NET Framework in the application.  The application will receive an event when a new ClickOnce version is added to the deployment location.  Once it receives this event, it can use the CheckForUpdateAsync and UpdateAsync methods in ApplicationDeployment to perform the actual update.

Since the **update** is simply a passive collection of files, the application is going to need to do something (unless you just want to go back to the default ClickOnce updating system).